# iam のポリシーで、別の policy をインクルードすることはできる?

Tags: aws, aws-iam

aws iam で policy をぽちぽち設定していて、今自分の作成しているこの policy に対して、他の policy を取り込めたらいいのにな、と思いました。特に aws managed policy に対して。

#### 質問

- aws iam にて、ある policy から他の policy を include することは可能でしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import ということはできる様子です。これは何かというと、既存の policy の json のエントリーをまるっとコピーして今作業中の policy に追記する、という動作をしている様子です。 参考: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_create.html#access_policies_create-copy

なお、もし include 的な記述が json 上で可能であったとしたら、このような機能を実装する意義があまりなくなると思うので、 @Yoshi さんの仰るとおり、ポリシーのインクルード機能は存在しない様子です。

Answer (score 0):

ポリシーに他のポリシーをインクルードするような機能は無いかと思います。